# JavaScript custom function returning unexpected value

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got a bunch of `style.display`, `firstChild.data`, and `innerHTML` values that toggle between two options, and made a helper function for this use. It is:

```
function htmlToggle(elem, prop, newVal, oldVal){
    elem[prop] == oldVal ? elem[prop] = newVal : elem[prop] = oldVal;
}
```

This has worked with all my elements (around 10) except for the newest one. When I try toggling its display, nothing happens, even though I toggle a different div's display immediately after, and that works successfully (smooshing this div way out of position, because it fails to toggle off.

I did some debugging with `console.log`, and found that, for this element alone, `elem[prop] = ""`, when it reaches the function. All other elements have what I expect (should be `elem[prop] == oldVal ==> true`, to start).

Any ideas as to why this is? Here's the markup for the non-working element:

```
<div id="text-div" style='display:none'></div>
```

In a callback that will always precede the toggling, its style is reset with the following:

```
document.getElementById('text-div').style = 'display:block-inline';
```

So after that call, its style is `'display:block-inline'`, which is what I'll then use as the `oldVal` argument in `htmlToggle`. Here is the call to `htmlToggle`:

```
htmlToggle(document.getElementById('text-div').style, 'display', 'none', 'block-inline');
```

Note that this element is inline, in a section, with another div, which will expand to 100% of the line they share after `#text-div` goes to `display:none`.

The CSS for the `section`, `text-div`, and the other div in its line (`map`), is here:

```
section {
  width: 98%;
  height: 750px;
  background: RGB(240,240,240);
  margin: auto;
  padding: 10px;
} 

div#map { 
  width: 100%;
  height: 750px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

div#text-div {
  margin-left: 76%;
  width: 23%;
  height: 750px;
  background: RGB(240,240,240);
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

I've been using this function and this pattern all over the place, without any issues. This is stumping me. I could always just not use my helper function, rig up some boolean to tell me which value to toggle manually, and do it that way. But, I really want to understand why this isn't working, even if I use a workaround in the end.

Comment: `display:block-inline` should be `display:inline-block` and `id`'s should not contain `-` (hyphens).

Comment: @ScottMarcus There's nothing wrong with hyphens in ids.

Comment: They are legal, but often cause bugs when developers unwittingly believe that they are ok in JavaScript as well. Best to stay away from them as a convention.

Comment: @ScottMarcus they are also ok in JavaScript, depending on how you use them, of course... ;)

Comment: @webeno The hyphen in JavaScript is not a valid identifier. It's only use is for mathematical subtraction.

Comment: if you target to change `document.getElementById('text-div').style = 'display:block-inline';` (and indeed it's `inline-block`, as @ScottMarcus says above), shouldn't you call `htmlToggle(document.getElementById('text-div').style, 'display', 'block-inline', 'none');` (swap oldVal and newVal) instead...?

Comment: it's a toggle, doesn't matter what the current value was. The problem is the use of block-inline.

Comment: @GregBorbonus, you're right

Comment: @ScottMarcus as said, depends on how you use it, using `getElementById('text-div')` is perfectly valid, for example...

Comment: Is it me, or is the title (both the old and the new) misleading? The `htmlToggle` function in question is not returning anything, so it can't be returning an unexpected value...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I was the one who changed the title, feel free to change it to whatever you think is best, you have sufficient reputation for that... ;)

Comment: @webeno Your example is not relevant. You are talking about a string, where any character is legal. My entire point was staying away from hyphens as identifiers.

Comment: @ScottMarcus you tend to confuse things, which is why you should stay away from hyphens, indeed. :) The OP used a hypen in an id that later on was called as a string inside the `getElementById` function, so it is perfectly valid... we could talk about possibilities of making mistakes in code, but then using a hyphen would not be the only thing...

Comment: I'm not confusing anything. I'm talking about a simple best-practice. You are the one confusing the point that is being made.

Comment: Thanks all for the comments! I especially appreciate the best practice concerns you're bringning up. I'm new to js, html, css, fairly new as a programmer in general, so value the feedback. Much appreciated.

Comment: @ScottMarcus if a developer unwittingly believes a hyphen is fine in javascript then he deserves to lose a day or two trying to "debug" the fact that he attempted to write something in javascript while lacking any understanding of language. There times when hand-holding and spoon-feeding are necessary, but something as core as "what characters are valid in my variable names" is seriously not one of them.

Comment: @webeno I do indeed have the rep, but I'm not clear on what exactly the question is, and therefore don't have the knowledge to change it :)

Comment: @abluejelly We can continue this in a chat all day, but your point is oversimplified. Best-practices exist for a variety of reasons, not the least of which is to allow for groups of developers (of all skill levels) work productively as a team. No one "deserves" to lose a day or two when simple practices can avoid it.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan it took me a moment to give that title, but I thought it was a bit better than the previous one... ;)

Comment: @ScottMarcus I feel the best practice of requiring entry-level competence  (and/or the ability to recognize when out of their depth and seek help) before letting someone work on something is a bit better of a policy, but to each his own.

Comment: @abluejelly Well, it's good to know that there are developers, like yourself, out there that never make mistakes. :)

Comment: @ScottMarcus Entry-level competency is perfection? Wow. The bar is that low? I guess that's why all the programmer jobs I see nowadays require 4 years experience or a master's....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change it from `block-inline` to `inline-block` like so:

```js
function htmlToggle(elem, prop, newVal, oldVal) {
  
  elem[prop] == oldVal ? elem[prop] = newVal : elem[prop] = oldVal;
}

function toggle_test() {
  htmlToggle(document.getElementById('text-div').style, 'display', 'none', 'inline-block');
}
```

```html
<div id="text-div" style='display:none'>BLAHBLAH</div>
<button onclick="toggle_test();">TEST</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById('text-div').style = 'display:block-inline';` is not the correct way to set the style via javascript. this is presumably overwriting all other styles on the element. you should do this instead:

```
document.getElementById('text-div').style.display = 'inline-block';
```